# Word counting function in python

Tags: python, string, count

I need to create a function in python called word that accepts a sentence and counts the total number of words and numbers.For instance

```
words('testing 1 2 testing')
```

should return

```
{'testing': 2, 1: 1, 2: 1}
```

I am currently using the code below but the output is taking every thing as a string even the numbers.

```
from collections import Counter
def words(sentence):
    return Counter(map(str, sentence.split()))
```

Comment: Great. What have you tried so far? Can you show your code and explain what difficulties you are having?

Comment: So, you are looking to make the "numbers" as int-types in your dictionary? right?

Comment: Python does not automatically convert strings to numbers when possible. Do the conversion yourself with a try/except.

Comment: yes am looking to make the "numbers" as int-types in my dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand your solution. Just check for `isdigit` in each iteration and perform your increment accordingly.

```
s = 'testing 1 2 testing'

d = {}
for word in s.split():
    word = int(word) if word.isdigit() else word
    if word in d:
        d[word] += 1
    else:
        d[word] = 1
```

Will output:

```
{1: 1, 2: 1, 'testing': 2}
```

Comment: Thanks very much .You are a saviour